# Why do my bulbs flicker with a TCP 1-gang Smart Switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, smart-switch

I just had a TCP 1-Gang Smart Switch installed to control two outside wall lamps (Pictured - and it is NOT a dimmer) and the LED bulbs flicker and go dim when I switch on. But it is supposed to be LED compatible.

I have tried a wide range of LED bulbs and the problem remains. I bought the switch new and provided it to the electrician who is 25 years served, so it is not his fault-the common "neutral wire" issue is not a factor either. Can anyone shed any light - no pun - because it is useless as things stand.

[image]

Comment: Even experienced people make mistakes. Have you asked the electrician to come back and double check the work? Sounds like there's a loose wire somewhere.

Comment: Try an incandescent lamp in the fixture. If that flickers, then it's definitely not LED incompatibility. Could be the switch or the wiring is defective. If it does *not* flicker, the switch might have a minimum current requirement. Try a larger LED, or put a small 4 watt incandescent night-light across the LED.